# Reassigning value in dataset based on a subset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question regarding how to assign a value considering a dataset and a subset of itself.
I created a new column called 'F' with default value 0 in my original dataset:

```
df['F']=0
```

Then I created a subset `sf1` where date was set to `2020-05-20`:

```
sf1 =df[df['Date']=='2020-05-20']
```

I would like to assign -1 to all the accounts in sf1, changing this value in the original dataset. I tried as follows:

```
for i, s in sf1.iterrows():
    df.loc[s['f'], 'f'] = -1
```

but it gives me -1 in wrong rows.

For example:
originally I have (df)

```
Date                  F
2020-05-20            0
2020-06-21            0
2020-01-12            0
...
```

and I create a subset (sf1)

```
Date                  F
2020-05-20            0
```

I would like to have

```
   Date                  F
    2020-05-20            1
    2020-06-21            0
    2020-01-12            0
...
```

but actually I am getting

```
   Date                  F
    2020-05-20            0
    2020-06-21            0
    2020-01-12            1
```

Can you please tell me where I am making the mistake?

Date is 'O' (but I would actually prefer to have a date format, rather than an object)

Comment: `df.loc[df['Date']=='2020-05-20','f']=-1`.

Comment: thanks @Quang Hoang. In case I had more conditions, for example `date= 2020-05-20` and `2020-05-12`, would it be ok to write `df.loc[df['Date']=='2020-05-20' & f['Date']=='2020-05-12'  ,'f']=-1`?

Comment: I would probably do something like ```df.loc[df['Date'].isin('2020-05-20' , '2020-05-12')  ,'f']=-1```

Comment: fixing Parmandeep's syntax slightly: `df.loc[df['Date'].isin(['2020-05-20', '2020-05-12']),'f']=-1`